# Recreating an object and DI

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I'm writing a class that works with an API Client object that sometimes becomes corrupted and has to be recreated from inside the object that uses it. What is the best way to do this using Dependency Injection? I'm hesitant to call the DI framework from inside the class since it makes my code dependent on it.

```
public class MyObject
{
    protected IMyAPIClient Client { get; set; }

    public MyObject(IMyAPIClient client)
    {
        Client = client;
    }

    protected async Task<ReturnType> Run<ReturnType>(Func<Task<ReturnType>> action, int attempt = 1)
    {
        try
        {
            return await action();
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            Client = await GetNewClient();
            if(attempt > MAX_ATTEMPTS)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Failed {attempt} times", exception);
            }
            
            return await Run(action, attempt++);
        }
    }

    protected async Task<IMyAPIClient> GetNewClient()
    {
        // what to do here?
    }
}
```

One solution that I came up with was to implement IMyAPIClient in a class that knows the type of IMyAPIClient and recreates it, thus circumventing the DI framework. I wonder if this is sensible or if there is a better way to do it?

Comment: If your IMyAPIClient instance is unstable, I would have tried to fix that. If you rephrase your question and add the code that causes the trouble, maybe someone in here can find the real issue. BR

Comment: What IoC framework are you using? If you are using Autofac, for example, it is easy - just inject a func.

Comment: _It's generally better to find out the cause of the problem rather than replace it.  Else we never learn_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a factory class that creates the IMyAPIClient.
This way I can handle the dependency injection in this factory class without making other code dependent on the DI framework.

```
public class MyObject
{
    protected IMyAPIClientFactory ClientFactory { get; set; }

    public MyObject(IMyAPIClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        ClientFactory = clientFactory;
        Client = clientFactory.CreateClient();
    }

    protected async Task<ReturnType> Run<ReturnType>(Func<Task<ReturnType>> action, int attempt = 1)
    {
        try
        {
            return await action();
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            Client = await clientFactory.CreateClient();
            if(attempt > MAX_ATTEMPTS)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Failed {attempt} times", exception);
            }
            
            return await Run(action, attempt++);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to fix the problems with the ApiClient. Using workarounds for buggy code is rarely a good idea, but might some times be required for third party code. If the problem is in third party code it might also be advisable to put it in a separate process, otherwise you cannot know if failures have some unexpected side-effects.

To create new objects I would suggest injecting a factory of some kind. Exactly how this is done would depend on the DI/IoC framework. Simplest might be a `Func<IMyAPIClient>`, but an alternative would be an explicit factory-class. You can chose if the factory should use the IoC container to construct the object, or just construct it directly. Also, some IoC framework will handle factories in some special way, while others might require factories to be registered just like everything else. Check the documentation for your framework to see how factories should be managed.

I would also recommend moving the restart logic to a decorator if possible. That way it is separated from the usage, and should be more flexible in case there are multiple users, or the logic needs to be updated. However, registering decorators can be a bit tricky to ensure they are working correctly, but this will also depend on your IoC framework.